0-10V LED Indicator with LM339
I’m following up on this question: 0-10V LEDs Indicator.
The solution provided by @marcus-müller seemed the most suitable to me, so I tried designing a circuit based on that approach.
To summarize, I want to light up LEDs based on the measured voltage. I slightly modified the behavior, adding 4 LEDs instead of 3, with the following logic:

L1 turns on when V >= 2.5V.
L2 turns on (while L1 remains on) when V >= 5V.
L3 turns on (while L1 and L2 remain on) when V >= 7.5V.
L4 turns on (while L1, L2, and L3 remain on) when V >= 10V.

For that I have:

A 2.5V reference input to the op-amps, generated using a TL431.
A supply voltage Vcc = 10V.
An input voltage Vin to apply the logic.

I chose a constant Vcc supply to avoid brightness variations based on the input voltage.
I’ve also simulated the circuit and didn’t experience any major issues. However, I’d like to ask if you can spot any significant mistakes or have any advice or suggestions for me. I have very little experience in circuit design, so I’d appreciate your input.
Thank you!


Thank you for asking a new question, instead of diluting an existing one. A solution like this could work because you have a fixed, always-on 10V supply to power the comparators. In your original question it was implied that the supply itself varied from 0 to 10V. These are very different scenarios.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. Better approach?
You've taken the rather unusual approach of having the same reference for each comparator and individual dividers on each signal input. This might be a good approach if you want to be able to adjust the threshold on each comparator because you could then replace each pair of resistors with a potentiometer.
A more normal way would be to create a potential divider ladder or chain (with half the number of resistors) as shown in Figure 1. Then VIN is applied to all the inputs directly.

Tips:

Try to draw the schematic so that the inputs are on the left and outputs on the right.
V+ should be at the top and current flowing downwards to GND or V- (as much as reasonably possible).
GND symbols should point down (to the ground).

There's a super thread at Rules and guidelines for drawing good schematics which is well worth a couple of reads.

I recommended that approach, because the lowest threshold voltage in that linked question (2.5 V) just happened to coincide with an (undivided) TL431 output (2.495 V), and all other thresholds where much higher. But your resistor ladder approach would work just as well when we swap the role of reference and input voltage (and comparator inputs).

https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/p8tm2fpfcbqy/leds-voltage-display/
Ok, first of all, thank you for the excellent suggestions. Here's what I’ve done based on your advice: I skipped the TL431 and will use Vcc directly as the reference voltage. I’ve calculated the potential divider ladder so that the LEDs turn on when Vin reaches specific thresholds (10%, 30%, 60%, 90%).I’ve adjusted the resistances, selecting standard values as recommended by Spehro.
Better now?

Looks okay. 2.5k is not a standard resistor value. You might choose 2.4K or 2.49k.
You only need 1mA for the TL431 to regulate  so maybe you can use the same resistor value for RX2 (about 3mA rather than 7.5mA). Or use 4.7k, 4.99k etc.
Best to put a 100nF bypass capacitor across the LM339 supply pins (near it).
Your approach of dividing the input voltage has the disadvantage of loading the input, however it means that the state is defined with an open input (all LEDs off). The LM339 has a negative bias current so it would otherwise tend to turn all the LEDs on. It could be replaced with a single chain of resistors (30k/10k/5k/15k in this particular case), saving a few parts.
Note that your circuit (same with the chain of resistors) violates the input range for at least one comparator but it’s actually okay in this particular case since at least one input for each comparator would always be within range and positive wrt ground and less than about 30V**). For example when the input is 10V the 2.5V comparator has 10V on the inverting input, which is definitely outside the input range of about 0V to 8V with a 10V supply. As I said though, it's okay in this particular case since the non-inverting input is within range. Be careful of this point in your future designs or you will get burned. Many other seemingly similar parts could be damaged if the input went slightly higher than 10V or will have an undefined output when an input is out of range.
Using the resistor chain requires solving a system of 3 simultaneous equations, which is inconvenient, because the thresholds interact. It happens to work out to nice numbers in this particular case though.
You can increase the divider resistor values in your circuit somewhat to reduce loading, 10x higher is definitely okay.
\$**\$ Many op-amps and comparators won't tolerate  input voltages much beyond their positive or negative rails and can be damaged. The LM339 allows positive input voltages to exceed the positive supply rail.

As shown by Transistor's answer (and not mentioned by me in that other answer), you could change your individual voltage dividers for one large ladder of resistors. Calculating the resistor values isn't hard – just a linear system of equations. However, your current approach is nice in its simplicity and its individual adjustability.
The practical concerns I have with your circuit (I have the same aesthetic/clarity concerns as Transistor with your schematic) are:

You'd need a decoupling capacitor (10 nF to 100 nF should do) close to your quad comparators VCC.
(10 + 10) kΩ in parallel to (10 + 20) kΩ in parallel to (10 + 30) kΩ (in total, a little more than 9 kΩ) are quite a high load for a signal source. I'd go for 1 MΩ where you currently use 10 kΩ (so (1+1) MΩ, (1+2) MΩ, and (1+3) MΩ, respectively), so that you load your "signal under test" source with a few µA instead of a couple mA. This is only relevant if that voltage source isn't designed to deliver several mA anyways.


Thanks for your suggestions. Adding the capacitor here: https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/p8tm2fpfcbqy/leds-voltage-display/
Do you think it is good enough now? Obviously, I will replace all the amplifiers with the LM339. I used the op-amps because, in CircuitLab, it’s not possible to set the supply voltage and the corresponding GND for the comparators. Thanks

Your previous question implied that the supply itself varied between 0V and 10V, which severely limited your options. This new design requires a fixed and always-on supply of 10V, but it greatly simplifies things. There are still some issues to address, though.
The comparators in the LM339 should not have both inputs simultaneously at a potential greater than \$V_{CC}-2V\$. See the LM339 datasheet, page 2, under "Input Common Mode Voltage Range", and be sure to read note 5. To ensure that this condition never occurs, it is preferable to divide all potentials down to a level well under 10V, say 5V, by dividng by 2. Our reference potential (from the TL431) could be +5V:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Do the same with input potential \$V_{IN}\$:

simulate this circuit
Now you can safely apply potentials Y and X1..X4 to the inputs of your comparators:

simulate this circuit
In fact, input potential \$V_{IN}\$ can rise to +16V, and this circuit will still function just fine. This design is also very immune to supply voltage fluctuations. I believe it should work with any supply voltage from 8V to 30V or so, without any issues, the only visible change being LED brightness.

You don't have to use a TL431, a regular 5.1V zener diode will provide similar results, if a little less precise:

simulate this circuit

Following your suggestions, I changed it in this: https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/p8tm2fpfcbqy/leds-voltage-display/
Any other suggestion? Thank you!

@sabruri1 That's a nice DIY TL431, for a simulator that doesn't have one! I presume that's just for simulation, since you still need a 2.5V source, and considering that you could replace that whole fake TL431 with a single 5V source instead. However, you did remind me that I should suggest using a regular zener diode, instead of a TL431, which would further simplify the design, and which I've added to my answer.

Yes exactly. It's just for simulation purposes :)
Do you think the resistor values I selected are okay? I ran some simulations on the currents flowing, and they’re all quite low. At most, it’s about 14mA when all the LEDs are on. :)

If you have a regulated supply (e.g., 5V), there is no need for the TL431 (with a decent LDO the regulated supply will be about as accurate as the TL431 anyway.)
Then this simple circuit would suffice (simulate it here):

Design Notes

Inputs are scaled so that they do not exceed 5V-2V = 3V.
5V logic supply for LM339, threshold voltage divider and LEDs.
Monitor voltage scaled to limit input to 3V @ Monitor = 15V

With a known voltage (that is, 5V) we can use a fixed divider to make the threshold voltages. These thresholds are scaled down to match the input scaling: 2V, 1.5V, 1V and 0.5V for thresholds at 10V, 7.5V, 5V and 2.5V.
Here's another idea, but it will be less accurate (simulate it here):

This approach relies on the FET theshold voltage of about 1.5V. Unlike the comparator version, this can be powered by the monitored voltage. Burden is about 1mA for the resistors at max voltage, plus whatever the LEDs draw.
The LED drives have current limiting to about 3.1mA, to keep their brightness fairly consistent across the input range. This can be adjusted by changing the 150 ohm sense resistor.
FETs can be 2N7002, BSS138 or other common types that have Vgs threshold of about 1.5V. Check the FET datasheet and adjust the voltage dividers to hit the values you need. Transistors can be any common switching type, like 2N3904.
